# Breaking up a data frame time series column into segments seperated by date time [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with a Dataframe indexed by date time in the format - `'2022-04-01 11:52:39+00:00'`. For one task I will need to split the data from one column in particular into a number of separate time series. Since it is two months of data, this could be 8 separate one-week time series or roughly 60 one-day time series. The interval does not matter at this point, but I am not sure how to break my data into separate series? I'd be open to inserting segments from the existing data frame column into a new data frame (one column for each new segment), or other approach suggested.

For example, when trying to create a new time series for just the first day:

```
TS_1 = DF['Column_Name'][2022-04-01 11:52:39+00:00:2022-04-01 23:57:39+00:00]
```

Which returns the SyntaxError: 'leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers'

Comment: Therefore, do you want to split your db based on days, weeks or months?

Comment: On a side note: You get the syntax error because your timestamp either needs to be a string or it needs to be a timestamp object

Comment: do you have unique timestamps?

Comment: To answer questions submitted so far: (1) weeks would be desirable, (2) I believe it is a timestamp object right now but I will dig into this one, thanks. (3) Yes they are unique (as in no duplicates).